# what's the shell command for dash screenshot application?

Tags: command-line, unity-dash, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I know in ubuntu, I can use Screenshot application using which I can take a screen shot for selected window. This means there is the application already on ubuntu. What's the command line command for that application? (I know gnome-screenshot lets us take the whole screenshot, but I want to select a region when taking the shot.)

Comment: `gnome-screenshot -a`

Comment: Like this? https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/taking-screenshots-in-linux-using-gnome-screenshot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to grab a screenshot of window, use this command
`gnome-screenshot -w`

In order to grab an area, use this command
`gnome-screenshot -a`

[image]

[image]

here is the link for source http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-screenshot.1.html

```
   -c, --clipboard
          Send the grab directly to the clipboard.

   -w, --window
          Grab the current active window instead of the entire screen.

   -a, --area
          Grab an area of the screen instead of the entire screen.

   -b, --include-border
          Include the window border within the screenshot.

   -B, --remove-border
          Remove the window border from the screenshot.

   -p, --include-pointer
          Include the pointer with the screenshot.

   -d, --delay=SECONDS,
          Take the screenshot after the specified delay [in seconds].

   -e, --border-effect=EFFECT,
          Add an effect to the outside of the screenshot border.  EFFECT  can  be  ``shadow''
          (adding  drop  shadow), ``border'' (adding rectangular space around the screenshot)
          or ``none'' (no effect).  Default is ``none''.

   -i, --interactive
          Interactively set options in a dialog.

   -f, --file=FILENAME
          Save screenshot directly to this file.

   --display=DISPLAY
          X display to use.

   -?, -h, --help
          Show a summary of the available options.
```